# Declaration and Definition of Function in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

One of the most common feature I used in xcode4.3 is to right click and go to the definition and or declaration of the function.

Sometimes I want to know the type of a property. Obviously I need to see the declaration. I click definition and it goes to the @synthesize line that's not helping.

Sometimes I want to know how a function is defined, I click definition and it goes to declaration with no easy way to go to the definition.

Is there some sense to this? Why they don't have declaration and definition? Where do you go if you click definition anyway? Declaration or definition?

Answer (score 0):

Won't control-left click take you to the definition. It could be cylinder-left double click, I'm not at my Mac right now but one of them takes me to the definition   Good luck

Comment: ctrl left click is like rightclick. That's what I always do to no effect.